# Are there any REST API builders with Cloud code?

Tags: cloud, multi-tenant, saas

Are there any REST API creator platforms?
I see Swapper as API builder alone without business logic and just for documentation. Is it possible to find a platform like Parse where I can develop Multi-Tenant apps , create REST API to connect from FrontEnd?

Comment: will this be helpful for you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/